# Sealing siding at foundation wall

Tags: pest-control, sealing, siding

I've been trying to determine if and how siding (aluminum in my case) should be sealed along the bottom edge at the foundation wall.

I've found some small gaps that last summer let ants in and I'm thinking that is how mice are getting into my attic as well.
I may not be searching for the answer correctly. Most results are about sealing your house before siding or sealing around windows.

Haven't found the rules for sealing at the foundation wall.

I figure it has to been done correctly fore water and moisture control.
Anyone know the right way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation, cedar siding that comes down to within a foot or two of the ground, depending on where around the house you are.

I kill the ants, foundation spray, shake pellets. Ants are, for the most part, smarter than I am and will always find a crack or crevice I didn't and they aren't afraid of heights.

I would never seal my siding at the bottom. Depends on different situations, the house is 60ish years old. Well before things were tight and meant to be tight. I don't want to trap moisture in a space that was not built for it and where this house needs to breathe or weep excess moisture. Could be wrong, but there is a reason you don't seal stucco there either, water needs an out (I am North East if location and weather matters to you).

Comment: Maybe I should concentrate on sealing the sheathing to the foundation wall. Doing that behind siding may be tricky though.

Comment: Yeah, I can't imagine it in my situation. Sounds like a ton of work to pull that off and the imho the ants would just head for the nearest window. I have some drama every year... the first year was spray, pellets, and external liquid baits. Now it is just management, but i stay on top of them